# how to make an image link ask the user if they want to download it, instead of displaying it in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page full of images. Currently, each image is a link that opens the image in a new tab. I want that image link, when clicked, to ask the user if they want to save it. How would I got about doing that?

Comment: Would you accept redirecting to a different page?  You could intercept the click using JavaScript I think...

Comment: I think that only javascript and HTML is not enough to do this. You'll need a server side script like PHP / ASP ... For php, please visit `http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php` for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serve the file with MIME type of application/octet-stream on the server to improve your chances of getting a download prompt to show, but ultimately it's up to the browser to decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is browser behavior and is something that you can't code directly into your web pages.  If the browser knows how to display a file of a particular type (which most browsers deduce from the MIME type and the file extension on the URL, if any), then it will attempt to open it in most cases.  It is possible to configure the browser to behave differently, but this has to be done on the client machine by the user of that browser--and is something that you, the programmer, can't control.

You do have some options, though they aren't very attractive.  The most straightforward would be to put your image(s) inside of a zip file, which most browsers will attempt to download rather than open by default.